# Why will Rust integer types be deprecated soon?

Tags: rust, integer, deprecated, standard-library

I've noticed a deprecation note on the [Rust std page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html) next to `u8`, `i8`, `u16` and so on:

[image]

What is going on, and what will the replacement be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The types themselves aren't being deprecated, just the modules named e.g. `std::i8` which contain constants. For example, `std::i8::MIN` is being replaced with `i8::MIN` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i8.html)). The deprecation notice says:

```
Deprecating in a future Rust version: all constants in this module replaced by associated constants on i8
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the exact things being deprecated are the _modules_ named `std::i8` and so on, which contain those constants.